# How to use AJAX with Eloquent ORM to delete records?

Tags: php, ajax, eloquent, slim

I'm using Slim framework + Eloquent ORM. I want to delete records with an ajax request. Only problem is that when I press the button to trigger the request, I get a 405 (method not allowed) error back. My route is a delete route and I've set the type to DELETE as well

what I have for my AJAX request so far:

```
$(".deleteYell").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
        token = $(this).data("token");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/yell/"+id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "_method": 'DELETE',
            "_token": token,
        },
        success: function ()
        {
            console.log("it Work");
        }
    });

    console.log("It failed");
});
```

my route is as follows:

```
$this->delete('/yell/{id}', 'UserController:deleteYell')->setName('deleteYell');
```

and here's the button that is used to delete the post:

```
<button class="deleteYell" data-id="{{ post.id }}" data-token="{{ csrf }}" type="button" name="button">Delete</button>
```

What should I change for this to work?

Comment: Are you sure you included the route file?

Comment: You have this route in a `$app->group(..)` correct? could you show that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use POST method.give it a try

```
$(".deleteYell").click(function(){
var id = $(this).data("id");
    token = $(this).data("token");
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/yell/"+id,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "id": id,
        "_method": 'DELETE',
        "_token": token,
    },
    success: function ()
    {
        console.log("it Work");
    }
});

console.log("It failed");
```

});